# spring-cloud-gcp-starter-bigquery ignores spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location from property file

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gcp, spring-cloud-gcp-bigquery

I am playing with spring gcp project. My [first example with GCP bucket](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/tree/master/spring-cloud-gcp-samples/spring-cloud-gcp-storage-resource-sample) works properly and uses correct google account which I pointed in the **property file**:

```
spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location=file:secret.json
```

On the next step I tried to repeat [bigQuery example](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/tree/ce2b52975000f780aafbc1efa655c4b7db6a2024/spring-cloud-gcp-samples/spring-cloud-gcp-bigquery-sample)

To achieve it I've created dataset on GCP side and added dataset name to the property file:

```
spring.cloud.gcp.bigquery.datasetName=my_dataset
```

Also I've copied **controller**:

```
@Controller
public class BigQueryController {
    @Autowired
    BigQuerySampleConfiguration.BigQueryFileGateway bigQueryFileGateway;

    @Autowired
    BigQueryTemplate bigQueryTemplate;

    @Value("${spring.cloud.gcp.bigquery.datasetName}")
    private String datasetName;

    @GetMapping("/bigquery")
    public ModelAndView renderIndex(ModelMap map) {
        map.put("datasetName", this.datasetName);
        return new ModelAndView("index.html", map);
    }

    /**
     * Handles a file upload using {@link BigQueryTemplate}.
     *
     * @param file      the CSV file to upload to BigQuery
     * @param tableName name of the table to load data into
     * @return ModelAndView of the response the send back to users
     * @throws IOException if the file is unable to be loaded.
     */
    @PostMapping("/uploadFile")
    public ModelAndView handleFileUpload(
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestParam("tableName") String tableName)
            throws IOException {

        ListenableFuture<Job> loadJob = this.bigQueryTemplate.writeDataToTable(
                tableName, file.getInputStream(), FormatOptions.csv());

        return getResponse(loadJob, tableName);
    }

    /**
     * Handles CSV data upload using Spring Integration {@link BigQuerySampleConfiguration.BigQueryFileGateway}.
     *
     * @param csvData   the String CSV data to upload to BigQuery
     * @param tableName name of the table to load data into
     * @return ModelAndView of the response the send back to users
     */
    @PostMapping("/uploadCsvText")
    public ModelAndView handleCsvTextUpload(
            @RequestParam("csvText") String csvData, @RequestParam("tableName") String tableName) {

        ListenableFuture<Job> loadJob = this.bigQueryFileGateway.writeToBigQueryTable(csvData.getBytes(), tableName);

        return getResponse(loadJob, tableName);
    }

    private ModelAndView getResponse(ListenableFuture<Job> loadJob, String tableName) {
        String message;
        try {
            Job job = loadJob.get();
            message = "Successfully loaded data file to " + tableName;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            message = "Error: " + e.getMessage();
        }

        return new ModelAndView("index")
                .addObject("datasetName", this.datasetName)
                .addObject("message", message);
    }
}
```

and **configuration**:

```
@Configuration
public class BigQuerySampleConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public DirectChannel bigQueryWriteDataChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public DirectChannel bigQueryJobReplyChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "bigQueryWriteDataChannel")
    public MessageHandler messageSender(BigQueryTemplate bigQueryTemplate) {
        BigQueryFileMessageHandler messageHandler = new BigQueryFileMessageHandler(bigQueryTemplate);
        messageHandler.setFormatOptions(FormatOptions.csv());
        messageHandler.setOutputChannel(bigQueryJobReplyChannel());
        return messageHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public GatewayProxyFactoryBean gatewayProxyFactoryBean() {
        GatewayProxyFactoryBean factoryBean = new GatewayProxyFactoryBean(BigQueryFileGateway.class);
        factoryBean.setDefaultRequestChannel(bigQueryWriteDataChannel());
        factoryBean.setDefaultReplyChannel(bigQueryJobReplyChannel());
        // Ensures that BigQueryFileGateway does not return double-wrapped ListenableFutures
        factoryBean.setAsyncExecutor(null);
        return factoryBean;
    }

    /**
     * Spring Integration gateway which allows sending data to load to BigQuery through a
     * channel.
     */
    @MessagingGateway
    public interface BigQueryFileGateway {
        ListenableFuture<Job> writeToBigQueryTable(
                byte[] csvData, @Header(BigQuerySpringMessageHeaders.TABLE_NAME) String tableName);
    }

}
```

and `index.html`(I don't think I should copy it here)

But when I try to write smth to the bigQuery dataset I see following error:

```
2020-03-03 15:01:32.147 ERROR 16224 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException: 404 Not Found
{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Not found: Dataset my_production_project:my_dataset",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Not found: Dataset my_production_project:my_dataset",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "notFound",
        "debugInfo": "[NOT_FOUND] time: 2020-03-03T04:01:31.971-08:00, Reason: code=NOT_FOUND message=Dataset bx-dev-contactmatch:my_dataset not found debug=time: 2020-03-03T04:01:31.971-08:00 errorProto=domain: \"cloud.helix.ErrorDomain\"\ncode: \"NOT_FOUND\"\nargument: \"Dataset\"\nargument: \"bx-dev-contactmatch:my_dataset\"\ndebug_info: \"time: 2020-03-03T04:01:31.971-08:00\"\n\n\tat com.google.cloud.helix.common.Exceptions$Public.resourceNotFound(Exceptions.java:281)\n\tat com.google.cloud.helix.common.Exceptions$Public.resourceNotFound(Exceptions.java:285)\n\tat com.google.cloud.helix.server.metadata.DatasetTrackerSpanner.lambda$getDatasetAsync$1(DatasetTrackerSpanner.java:236)\n\tat com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractTransformFuture$AsyncTransformFuture.doTransform(AbstractTransformFuture.java:213)\n\tat com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractTransformFuture$AsyncTransformFuture.doTransform(AbstractTransformFuture.java:202)\n\tat com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractTransformFuture.run(AbstractTransformFuture.java:118)\n\tat com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$5$1.run(MoreExecutors.java:1158)\n\tat com.google.common.context.ContextRunnable.runInContext(ContextRunnable.java:89)\n\tat com.google.common.context.ContextRunnable$1.run(ContextRunnable.java:78)\n\tat io.grpc.Context.run(Context.java:602)\n\tat com.google.tracing.GenericContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(GenericContextCallback.java:75)\n\tat com.google.common.context.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:74)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\n"
      }
    ],
    "status": "NOT_FOUND"
  }
}
] with root cause

com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 404 Not Found
{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Not found: Dataset my_production_project:my_dataset",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Not found: Dataset my_production_project:my_dataset",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "notFound",
        "debugInfo": "[NOT_FOUND] time: 2020-03-03T04:01:31.971-08:00, Reason: code=NOT_FOUND message=Dataset bx-dev-contactmatch:my_dataset not found debug=time: 2020-03-03T04:01:31.971-08:00 errorProto=domain: \"cloud.helix.ErrorDomain\"\ncode: \"NOT_FOUND\"\nargument: \"Dataset\"\nargument: \"bx-dev-contactmatch:my_dataset\"\ndebug_info: \"time: 2020-03-03T04:01:31.971-08:00\"\n\n\tat com.google.cloud.helix.common.Exceptions$Public.resourceNotFound(Exceptions.java:281)\n\tat com.google.cloud.helix.common.Exceptions$Public.resourceNotFound(Exceptions.java:285)\n\tat com.google.cloud.helix.server.metadata.DatasetTrackerSpanner.lambda$getDatasetAsync$1(DatasetTrackerSpanner.java:236)\n\tat com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractTransformFuture$AsyncTransformFuture.doTransform(AbstractTransformFuture.java:213)\n\tat com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractTransformFuture$AsyncTransformFuture.doTransform(AbstractTransformFuture.java:202)\n\tat com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractTransformFuture.run(AbstractTransformFuture.java:118)\n\tat com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$5$1.run(MoreExecutors.java:1158)\n\tat com.google.common.context.ContextRunnable.runInContext(ContextRunnable.java:89)\n\tat com.google.common.context.ContextRunnable$1.run(ContextRunnable.java:78)\n\tat io.grpc.Context.run(Context.java:602)\n\tat com.google.tracing.GenericContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(GenericContextCallback.java:75)\n\tat com.google.common.context.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:74)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\n"
      }
    ],
    "status": "NOT_FOUND"
  }
}
```

From the error we can see that app tries to access `my_production_project` which is not expected.

**secret.json** content:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "spring-samples-269912",
  "private_key_id": "04d22c73e3ef53dd82f20c322f91a79e2fbc76d9",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----******-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "spring-samples-service-account@spring-samples-269912.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "117486490087851987327",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/spring-samples-service-account%40spring-samples-269912.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

As you can see here `spring-samples-269912` project is mentioned.

How could I fix it ?

**P.S.**

Both examples(Gcp buckets and BigQuery) are resides in the same project so they use the same application.properties file and the same **secret.json**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem went away when I set

```
spring.cloud.gcp.bigquery.project-id=spring-samples-269912
```

or

```
spring.cloud.gcp.project-id=spring-samples-269912
```